# How to highlight the searched parts

Tags: php, search

This script can search but I want it to highlight the searched parts.

Example: 
Input: 'Hel'

Output 1: 'Hello everyone!'

Output 2: 'My life is like hell'

The page with the output needs no highlight the part 'hel' from hello and from hell (different font color or background color)

This is my Code:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("xxxxxx","xxx","xxxxx") or die("Kan geen verbinding maken met de server!");
mysql_select_db("xxxx") or die("Kan de ingevoerde database niet vinden");


    $query = $_GET['query'];

    $min_length = 0;

    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query);

        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product
            WHERE (UPPER(naam) LIKE UPPER('%".$query."%')) 
                OR (UPPER(titel) LIKE UPPER('%".$query."%')) 
                OR (UPPER(druk) LIKE UPPER('%".$query."%'))")  
          or die(mysql_error());


        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 

            echo "<table >";
            echo"<th>Auteur</th> <th>Titel</th> <th>Druk</th>"; 
            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){

               echo "<tr><td>" .
                '<a href="bio.php?naam='.$results["naam"].'">' . $results["naam"] . '</a><br>' .
                "</td> <td>" . 
                '<a href="article.php?id='.$results["id"].'">' . $results["titel"] . '</a><br>' . 
                "</td><td>" .
                $results['druk']. 
                "</td></tr>";

            }

            echo "<table>"; 
        }
        else{ 

            echo "<div style=\"text-align:center; padding-bottom: 10px; \"><br /><br />Geen resultaten, probeer het opnieuw of <a href=index.php>ga terug</a></div>";
        }

    }
    else{
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }
?>
```

Can someone help me and tell me what to do next?

Comment: @LajosVeres thnx for the reaction. Can you help me place this in my script?

Answer (score 0):

First of all ram your code down

1. Use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql*
2. Never trust request-paramters SQL-INJECTION $query = $_GET['query'];

When you have correct your code, just use a simple function in your while-loop eg

```
 $results["naam"] = str_replace($_GET['query'],$results["naam"],'<span class="highlight">'.$results["naam"].'</span>';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I will take a look at mysqli or PDO

Comment: I guess u mixed up some vars and at end is a missing ')'. Link to correct use of str_replace in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like this http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php

try

```
$highlightPart = str_replace($query, '<span class="myHighlightClass">' . $query . '</span>', $results["naam"]);
```

Here in your script:

```
<?php

mysql_connect('xxxxxx','xxx', 'xxxxx') or die('Kan geen verbinding maken met de server!');
mysql_select_db('xxxx') or die('Kan de ingevoerde database niet vinden');


    $query = $_GET['query'];

    $min_length = 0;

    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query);

        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

        $raw_results = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM product
            WHERE (UPPER(naam) LIKE UPPER(\'%' . $query . '%\')) 
                OR (UPPER(titel) LIKE UPPER(\'%' . $query . '%\')) 
                OR (UPPER(druk) LIKE UPPER(\'%' . $query . '%\'))')  
          or die(mysql_error());


        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 

            echo '<table>';
            echo '<th>Auteur</th> <th>Titel</th> <th>Druk</th>'; 
            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
                $highlightNaam = str_replace($query, '<span class="myHighlightClass">' . $query . '</span>', $results["naam"]);
                $highlightTitel = str_replace($query, '<span class="myHighlightClass">' . $query . '</span>', $results["titel"]);
               echo "<tr><td>" .
                '<a href="bio.php?naam=' . $results['naam'] . '">' . $highlightNaam . '</a><br>' .
                '</td> <td>' . 
                '<a href="article.php?id=' . $results['id'] . '">' . $highlightTitel . '</a><br>' . 
                '</td><td>' .
                $results['druk']. 
                '</td></tr>';

            }

            echo '<table>'; 
        }
        else{ 

            echo '<div style=\"text-align:center; padding-bottom: 10px; \"><br /><br />Geen resultaten, probeer het opnieuw of <a href=index.php>ga terug</a></div>';
        }

    }
    else{
        echo 'Minimum length is ' . $min_length;
    }
?>
```

Comment: thnx for the reaction.Where do i place this line in my code?

Comment: In your while loop before you echo. $highlightPart is the part between the a tags.

Comment: I updated my answer and added your code into it. Just copy paste and it should work.

Comment: And use ´" "´ only if you want do something like ´"That is my $var"´ otherwise use ´'That is my ' . $var´. Because if you use ´" "´ PHP will parse for variables like $var and this needs more server resources.

Comment: Its not working for me, or do I need to change the span for effect>?

Comment: Yes, I forgott to put the new vars between the a tags. Now the code should work. I guess u already did it in your code. And of course - you need to edit your css and give your class `myHighlightClass` another color.

Answer (score 0):

you can use function `str_replace()`

```
   $search_str=$_GET['query'];
   $replace_str='<font color="#value">'. $search_str.'</font>'; //you can change any style you like
   $outdata=str_replace($search_str,$replace_str,$results["titel"]);
   echo "<tr><td>" .
        '<a href="bio.php?naam='.$results["naam"].'">' . 
        $results["naam"] . 
        '</a><br>' .
        "</td> <td>" . 
        '<a href="article.php?id='.$results["id"].'">' .
         $outdata .                                       //the outdata with your style
        '</a><br>' . 
        "</td><td>" .
        $results['druk']. 
        "</td></tr>";
```

Comment: It sort of works. It echos the $outdata under the "titel"
(I also changed the #value in "black" bur nothing happend)